# Select column FROM table_name WHERE username=$_SESSION['username'] not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to take out *url* from the table **users** and insert it into *url* of a table **images** from the current user logged in. This code is not able to insert the *url* in the **images** table.

```
$uploaduser = $_SESSION["username"];
$selectuser = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$uploaduser",$db1);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectuser);
$pic = $row['url'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO images (image1, image_text1, uploaduser, url, date) VALUES ('$image1', '$image_text1' , '$uploaduser','$pic','$date')";

mysqli_query($db1, $sql);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Comment: This depends whether `username` is a varchar field or `numeric`

Comment: This could also be avoided with proper use of prepared statements.

Comment: The link (`$db1`) should be the first argument of `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: @Syscall , that code worked when I did not include the 'url' column. Now, just for testing, I tried putting $pic=$_SESSION ['username'] and it worked fine.

Comment: I was talking about the first query of your question (`mysqli_query($db1, "SELECT * FROM users...`)

Comment: Yes, @Syscall I tried that, but it didn't help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument should be the link (`$db1`).
Then, except if username is a numeric datatype, you should wrap the value using single quotes.

Try this :

```
$selectuser = mysqli_query($db1, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$uploaduser'");
```

**Important:** You should have a look to [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to secure your queries.

Comment: Thanks @Syscall, that really helped me! Great job!  I had been trying this the whole day...... :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepared statements, anyway from what it looks like,

```
$selectuser = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$uploaduser",$db1);
```

You have an error here. `mysqli_query` expects param 1 to be the connection variable and param 2 as query string, instead you have passed the second param as connection variable and the first param as the query string.

Also try to concatenate the variables instead of directly passing the variables into the query string.

Instead of

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO images (image1, image_text1, uploaduser, url, date) VALUES ('$image1', '$image_text1' , '$uploaduser','$pic','$date')";
```

Try

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO images (image1, image_text1, uploaduser, url, date) VALUES ('".$image1."', '".$image_text1."' , '".$uploaduser."','".$pic."','".$date."')";
```

Hope this helps.